# Устал изобретать велосипеды

Tags: c++, library

усиленно изучаю c++, делаю свои тестовые проектики, и, вроде бы, все даже хорошо, все работает, но, такое чувство, что я застрял на каком-то низкоуровневом, процедурном программировании, то есть, когда я что-то делаю и пытаюсь использовать вспомогательные библиотеки, то ничего толкового из этого не выходит и приходится "изобретать велосипед".
Как вообще у клалифицированных программистов это происходит при работе на реальных проектах? Откуда берете чьи-то наработки и т.п. Может знаете какие-нибудь полезные статьи, которые помогут разобраться, или просто поделитесь опытом)
Спасибо!

Comment: Да все также и у клалифицированных программистов, низкоуровневое и процедурное програмирование, велосипеды и прочее.

Comment: что вы подразумевается под "изобретать велосипед" ? Это какие-то велосипеды устраняющие/обходящие проблемы языка или велосипеды относящиеся к решаемой задаче?

Comment: а вы пробовали разделять задачу на подзадачи? Вот когда хорошо разделите, то решение многих подзадач может выполнять какая то  сущность или функция из стандарта   или другой библиотеки ( Boost  например) или поискать готовое решение в интернете.

Comment: поддерживаю @ARHovsepyan, разделите например для начала на пользовательский интерфейс, сетевой интерфейс (если есть), интерфейс к дискам/файлам и вычислительную часть

Comment: Да, я имею ввиду алгоритмы, обходящие проблемы языка, просто происходит это так часто, что такое ощущение, что проблема тут только я)
Вероятно это из-за того, что я не могу видеть исходный код того или иного класса и т.п. и, поэтому неправильно понимаю как оно все работает, и в более хитровыдуманном применении натыкаюсь на неприятности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос у вас немного обобщённый честно говоря, поэтому не буду говорить конкретно.

Для проблем устраняющих/обходящих языковые проблемы а также, например, недостатки стандартной библиотеки ознакомьтесь с [идиомами](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms) - уверен найдёте много техник для написания эффективного и простого С++ кода.

Касательно библиотек - тут все очень зависит от их предметной области, например если используется мат. либа то "не на гавнокодить" часто приравнивается к тому, чтобы правильно использовать API данной либы, что в свою очередь подразумевает некую осведомлённость в этой самой предметной области (допустим в лин. алгебре и численных методах), плюс по возможности детальное изучение его API.

Касательно реальных С++ проектов - в виду древности языка в 70-80 процентов случаев вся архитектура уже построена и реализована, поэтому тут важно разобраться с уже построенной структурой. 
Допустим, ваша задача специфична для проекта, и требует, например, частого обращения к внутренним API - в таком случае наработки, соответственно, берёте из уже существущей кодовой базы, где есть нечто реализованное и похожее на вашу задачу. В случае же с чем-то радикально новым которое интегрируется в проект, очень много наработок с пояснениями по многих областям `software engineering` a есть, например [тут](https://www.codeproject.com/).

Как-то так, надеюсь чем-то помог

Comment: *"вся архитектура уже построена и реализована группой опытных инженеров"* - такое ощущение, что вы никогда не работали с реальными проектами...

Comment: @user7860670 а у меня ощущение будто вы не работали, и заметьте, я указал в 70-80 процентов случаях, и речь шла о больших коммерческих проектах, а не о мелких опен сорсных - у каждого свой опыт и понимание "реального проекта"

Comment: Спасибо, да, помогли, стало понятно куда копать